# How do I get better control over screen brightness

Tags: display, dell-inspiron, brightness

I bought a Dell Inspiron (which runs Windows 7) and they seem to have done something to the brightness controls because it seems to be more coarse than I remember from my previous HP Pavilion (EDIT: yep. I can only change the brightness in jumps of 6). I wish to get a better control of the screen brightness to tune it to the specific sweet spot I'm interested in.

The model is N5110. 
Is there a program or setting that can do this for me?

Comment: Have same issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a Inspiron 1564 or similar chassis there is nothing you can do about it. If not try from the advanced power settings for the profile you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I also have an Inspiron. If you go to the control panel, then hit **"Mobility Center"**, it can be changed more precisely there. Alternatively you can hit **Windows Key + X** to open this.

[image]

Comment: Nope. It still wouldn't let mo have full control. It goes from 18 to 12.

Comment: Try scrolling or using keyboard arrows, as opposed to dragging.

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Can you give the specific model number?

Comment: The model is: N5110

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the Intel Graphics Media
   Accelerator HD icon in the lower right
   area of the task bar (I had to click on
   the up arrow to see it)
2. Select the Graphics Properties
   option from the menu
3. Then Select Power ---Power
   Features
4. On the right hand side there will be
   a drop down menu select the On
   Battery Option
5. Make sure the check box next to
   Display Power Saving Technology is
   not checked.
   And that is it. You should be able to change your brightness levels more precisely