# How can I get a better control over the brightness

Tags: windows-7, brightness, dell-xps

I have a Dell xps17 (windows 7) and I find the brightness control very annoying.

I often work during night time and the lower settings is fine but if I increase the brightness settings by just one step, the brightness is way to strong. I went in  Windows mobility center and it seems I can only increase the brightness by steps of 6. I have seen this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/287456/how-do-i-get-better-control-over-screen-brightness) but it's very old (2011) and the guy didn't receive an answer except "it's impossible", which seems outdated because I have found this software [Adjust Laptop Brightness](http://adjustlaptopbrightness.en.softonic.com/) which seems to do what I want

But I wonder if there isn't a better solution (without having to download something), or a safer software (like an open-source one) to do this pretty simple (at least it's what it seems to me) job.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Even if it's old, it's still the same question.  If you'd like newer/different answers to the existing question, please [place a bounty on it](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) instead of asking it again.  Also, if you've found a possible solution (the 3rd party software you've mentioned) why not help others out and add that as an answer to the existing question (as well)?

Answer (score 1):

It's not even workaround, just something to lower your pain. Please give [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) a try. I use it and I love it. This program makes your LCD more friendly for the eyes at night.

Comment: Thanks for this link, I have also find a similar [software](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) but I couldn't find if it can make the "brightness" more sensitive (not increase in jumps of 6 but 4 or even better 1)